# I was try to return a card using two map which nested but data is not showing up

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was trying to add data in Gotocart.jsx and was using a nested map but nothing is showing up on the page.

The Gotocart.jsx is below

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react'
import { data } from './Data'
import cartstyle from './cartstyle.css'
import Cartitems from './Cartitems';
import { infoarray } from './Menu';
import image73 from './assets/cake73.jpeg'
// import image73 from './assets/cake73.jpeg'
export default function Gotocart(props) {
  return (
    <div className='cartbody'>

      <div className="heading">
        <div></div>
        <div className="welcome">
          Welcome To the Cart
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="thanks">
        <div></div> THANKS FOR VISITING
      </div>
      <div className="cart-info" id='cartinformation'>
        {
          data.map((e) =>{
            return(
                infoarray.map((ank) =>{
                  if(ank==e.id){
                  return (<Cartitems key={e.id} name1={e.name} images1 ={e.images}/>);
                  }
                })
            )
          })
        }
      </div>

      <div className="order">
        <div></div>
        ORDER NOW
      </div>

    </div>
  )
}
```

This is the carditme.jsx which defines how a particular card will look like

```
import React from 'react'
import cartstyle from './cartstyle.css'
import { useState } from 'react';
import { data } from './Data';
import image73 from './assets/cake73.jpeg'
//  below is destructuring
export default function Cartitems(props) {
    return (
        <div>

            <div className="information">

                <div className="imagecart">
                    <img className='img12' src={props.images1} alt="error" />
                    <div className="nameofitem"> {props.name1} </div>
                </div>

                <div className="quantity">
                    <button className="minus">-</button>
                    <button className="quantity">1</button>
                    <button className="add">+</button>
                    <i className="fa-solid fa-trash"></i>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    )
}
```

The data stored in the infoarray is correct but still, something is wrong here. Moreover, when I am not using the outer map and clicking add to cart for 4 items, 4 cards show up in the Gotocart section.

edit->

[image: This is the error]

This is the code where `infoarray` is defined

```
import React from 'react'
import images from './assets/cake21.jpeg'
import image1 from './assets/cake53.jpeg'
import image2 from './assets/cake61.jpeg'
import image3 from './assets/cake81.jpeg'
import image4 from './assets/cake78.jpeg'
import flower16 from './assets/flower16.jpeg'
import { data } from './Data'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
const infoarray = [];
export { infoarray };
export const changedArray = newinfoArray => infoarray = newinfoArray;
export default function Menu(){
  return (
    <>
      <div className="go"   >
        <Link to="/cart">
          <i className="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping" />
        </Link>
        <div className="text">
          Go to cart
        </div>
      </div>
      </>
  )
}
```

and data is like this

```
export const data = [
    //  all itmes 
    {
        id:1 ,
        name: "Almond Cake" ,
        images : images01
    },
    
    {
        id:2 ,
        name: "Cartoon cake" ,
        images : images02
    },
    
    {
        id:3 , 
        name: "Choco pie cake " ,
        images : images03
    },
}]
```

Way more data here.

Comment: post what is in `infoarray` and what is in `data`

Comment: The query is solved sir thanks for your concern

Answer (score 1):

You have to return some `element` or a `fragment` or `null` when there is no match also please check the `key` (I have mentioned as **some_unique_key**)

```
<div className="cart-info" id="cartinformation">
      {data.map((e) => {
        return infoarray.map((ank) => {
          if (ank == e.id) {
            return <Cartitems key={ank.some_unique_key} name1={e.name} images1={e.images} />;
          }
          return null;
        });
      })}
    </div>
```

Comment: i read the doc and tried like this but still showing an error I have attached the image above please check

Comment: sorry I couldn't see an image ..

Comment: I have added now please see

Comment: this has syntax errors in it.

Comment: @Gabriele sir how can I fix this then can you please show

Comment: edited, please check now ....

Comment: error is gone but the data is not showing up, moreover when there is only one map function the infoarray one then the data is showing up

Comment: does `ank==e.id` it match only one result ?

Comment: infoarray have id and if data's id matched it .i.e. if ank==e.id then proceed.... this is what happening here

Comment: see [this e.g.](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-mopsa-njnnmv?file=/src/App.js) on how to map inside another map

Comment: Thank you so much, sir, I didn't put the semi colon in the code that's why it was not woking I cant believe this. thank you so much.  Plese update you answer so that I can mark it as correct

Comment: The code in the posted answer is completely wrong. If you have solved the real issue in the linked codepen, please bring the correct code in the answer.

Comment: sorry, @GabrielePetrioli can you please point out what is wrong ? I can take it off and happy to learn 

Comment: @KcH you have the `<>` inside the `map` which is a syntax error. It is `jsx` and should be `return`ed. Also the `infoarray` is inside `{}` but in js code (*not `jsx`*), so it is another syntax error.

Comment: Thanks @GabrielePetrioli I have understood, sorry I should have matched the sample sandbox to the linked answer, I would delete it for no more confusion ,,,,

Comment: Yes, I thought you will update the answer as I requested.

Comment: yeah sure let me update it real quick

Comment: Ok, but now the only difference for the original post code is the `return null`. And that was not the problem. So not sure what the fix really was. Not seeing any wrong-placed semicolons in the original code, as @Ankit mentions either.

Comment: so @GabrielePetrioli returning nothing when not matched is not really an issue  ...

Comment: Right, returning nothing means `undefined` and react does nothing with it.